# select all records between two dates using calendar

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to search record by two dates, the two dates will be selected by a user via calendar. This is how I wrote the query:

```
public List<Staff> GetStaff(DateTime DateOne, DateTime DateTwo, string staffColourCode)
{
    List<Staff> l= new List<Staff>();
    SqlConnection conn = new connection etc...
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE CAST(Time AS date) BETWEEN @Time and @Time", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateOne);


    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Staff s= new Staff();
        s.Name= reader["Name"].ToString();
        etc...

        l.Add(s);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return l;
}
```

In my database if i replace Time with some date then it works but how do i write a query that allows a users to select two dates and based on DateOne and DateTwo search the list of Staff who has a colour code of whatever a user selects e.g. Green, Yellow etc...

Comment: Well you're currently using `BETWEEN @Time AND @Time` - surely you want *two different* parameters, one for the start and one for the end...

Comment: Use `BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as comments above have stated you are only making use of one of your parameters

```
public List<Staff> GetStaff(DateTime DateOne, DateTime DateTwo,string color)
{
    //Some connection stuff
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM TableName 
                                          WHERE CAST(Time AS date)> @Time 
                                          and CAST(Time AS date)< @Time2
                                          and staffColorCode = @color", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", DateOne);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time2", DateTwo);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("color", color);

    //retrieve data
}
```

additional parameter added

Comment: i have not tested yet, but i think this is what i want. Final question   how would i add another WHERE word, so select data From and To where staff colour code is whatever is selected by a user.

Comment: Use `BETWEEN`. Only use this `WHERE` clause if you want to exclude entries where `Time = @Time` or `Time = @Time2`.

Comment: simply add another and clause to the statement see amended answer @ThorstenDittmar you correct however i prefer to write it this way as it allows you to comment out a line easier if required an also shows how and statements can be chained

Answer (score 2):

You need two different parameters:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName " + 
                                    "WHERE CAST(Time AS date) BETWEEN @DateOne and @DateTwo", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOne", DateOne);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTwo", DateTwo);
```